# Excel add data to WorksheetPart in code behind

Tags: c#, .net, excel, openxml, openxml-sdk

Hello guys I am creating an Excel file with 3 worksheets in the following code.

```
using (SpreadsheetDocument spreadSheet = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(path + @"\UrlReport.xlsx", SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook))
            {
                // create the workbook
                spreadSheet.AddWorkbookPart();
                spreadSheet.WorkbookPart.Workbook = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Workbook();

                // CREATE FIRST SHEET
                WorksheetPart newWorksheetPart1 = spreadSheet.WorkbookPart.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();

                newWorksheetPart1.Worksheet = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Worksheet();

                // create sheet data
                newWorksheetPart1.Worksheet.AppendChild(new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.SheetData());

                // save worksheet
                newWorksheetPart1.Worksheet.Save();

                // create the worksheet to workbook relation
                spreadSheet.WorkbookPart.Workbook.AppendChild(new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Sheets());
                spreadSheet.WorkbookPart.Workbook.GetFirstChild<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Sheets>().AppendChild(new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Sheet()
                {
                    Id = spreadSheet.WorkbookPart.GetIdOfPart(newWorksheetPart1),
                    SheetId = 1,
                    Name = "Sheet1"
                });

                //CREATE SECOND SHEET
                WorksheetPart newWorksheetPart2 = spreadSheet.WorkbookPart.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();
                newWorksheetPart2.Worksheet = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Worksheet();

                // create sheet data
                newWorksheetPart2.Worksheet.AppendChild(new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.SheetData());

                // save worksheet
                newWorksheetPart2.Worksheet.Save();

                // create the worksheet to workbook relation
                spreadSheet.WorkbookPart.Workbook.GetFirstChild<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Sheets>().AppendChild(new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Sheet()
                {
                    Id = spreadSheet.WorkbookPart.GetIdOfPart(newWorksheetPart2),
                    SheetId = 2,
                    Name = "Sheet2"

                });

                //CREATE THIRD SHEET
                WorksheetPart newWorksheetPart3 = spreadSheet.WorkbookPart.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();
                newWorksheetPart3.Worksheet = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Worksheet();

                // create sheet data
                newWorksheetPart3.Worksheet.AppendChild(new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.SheetData());

                // save worksheet
                newWorksheetPart3.Worksheet.Save();

                // create the worksheet to workbook relation
                spreadSheet.WorkbookPart.Workbook.GetFirstChild<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Sheets>().AppendChild(new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Sheet()
                {
                    Id = spreadSheet.WorkbookPart.GetIdOfPart(newWorksheetPart3),
                    SheetId = 3,
                    Name = "Sheet3"
                });

                spreadSheet.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Save();
            }
```

I need to know how I can populate the cells of the 3 datasheets.  I need to just add strings to some cells that are probably going to be in some datatable or multidimensional array.

Answer (score 10):

```
private static void InsertValuesInWorksheet(WorksheetPart worksheetPart, IEnumerable<string> values)
{
    var worksheet = worksheetPart.Worksheet;
    var sheetData = worksheet.GetFirstChild<SheetData>();
    var row = new Row { RowIndex = 1 };  // add a row at the top of spreadsheet
    sheetData.Append(row);

    int i = 0;
    foreach (var value in values)
    {
        var cell = new Cell
                            {
                                CellValue = new CellValue(value),
                                DataType = new EnumValue<CellValues>(CellValues.String)
                            };

        row.InsertAt(cell, i);
        i++;
    }
}
```

This method will add a new row to a specified worksheet and fill the row's cells with the values from an array.  In your code sample, it could be called like this:

```
var values = new[] {"foo", "bar", "baz"};

InsertValuesInWorksheet(newWorksheetPart1, values);
InsertValuesInWorksheet(newWorksheetPart2, values);
InsertValuesInWorksheet(newWorksheetPart3, values);
```